# A thought experiment about light passing conductor

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

We know that light is an electromagnetic wave, so if we are able to build a surface with help of transparent but conducting material we will be able to build a conducting solid, so there will be no electric field inside the electric field inside the solid conductor.

Now my question is how will light incident on this surface behave, will it pass through considering a transparent surface? Or something different will happen because light is nothing but a mutual change in the electric and magnetic field causing propagation perpendicular to both electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. If the material is transparent, this means that light will pass through it. So what is the problem? What does your last sentence imply? Note also that conductors in general are not transparent. See [What mechanisms allow conductors to be transparent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59327)

Comment: no, my question is if it is a conductor then it will disrupt the electric field inside the conductor thus bring some kind of hindrance to the propagation of light.(let me go through the link u have sent)

Comment: There is no static field inside a conductive sphere, but aternating fields like light are allowed. So making a clear sphere conductive would not affect light passing through it. BTW, indium tin oxide is the most widely used transparent conductor found in common LCD screens: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide

Comment: Materials that are transparent are not conducting at optical frequencies.  Indium tin oxide is conducting at very low frequencies, but not at optical frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a transparent material will let (visible) light pass through, regardless of its other properties. If the material were to reflect or absorb the light it would lose its status of transparency.

However, some materials are transparent to certain wavelengths of light, but reflect or absorb others. Glass, for example, is transparent for visible wavelengths but will, in general reflect infrared light.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a transparent material (at a given frequency) will let light through, thereby allowing nonzero electric fields (of that frequency) inside the material.

Similarly, by definition (or by an implication that's close enough that it counts as a definition), a material that conducts at a given frequency does not allow electric fields at that frequency inside the bulk of the material.

The obvious conclusion is that a material cannot be both transparent and conducting (at the same frequency) at a given time. That obvious conclusion is correct.

Or, put another way, your premise is inconsistent, and no meaningful analysis is possible inside it.